# Sometimes question is asked which was already questioned previously

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, acceptable-answer

So,

> What are the possible ways to stop questioning the same question one has asked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you ask your question, use the search functionality to see if the question has already been asked.

Also, as you type your question, the page will make suggestions as to similar questions.

Worst case, members of the community will flag it for you if it is a dupe.

All this information is in the [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) which I would suggest everyone should read before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks TRiG - blimming smartphone autocomplete!